# Implicit conversion of NSInteger error

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

Using MagicalRecord, I am trying to get the record with a particular **clientNumber** which is a NSInteger (defined as int16 as the data type).

This is my line of code where I'm getting the error:

```
ClientInfo *clientSelected = [ClientInfo MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"aClientNumber" withValue: clientNumber inContext:localContext];
```

UPDATE: This is the definition of MR_findFirstByAtytribute:

```
MR_findFirstByAttribute:(NSString *) withValue:(id)
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Implicit conversion of NSInteger (aka int) is disallowed with ARC
```

For the life of me, I don't see what's wrong.  ClientInfo is defined as

```
@interface ClientInfo : NSManagedObject
```

Comment: It's saying you're trying to use NSInteger -- a "scalar" -- where an object pointer is expected.

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense to me... then what's it supposed to be?

Comment: We can't tell precisely what it's supposed to be without seeing the MR_findFirstAttribute method description, but it it's expecting an NSNumber you need to use `[NSNumber numberWithInt:clientNumber]`

Comment: (I agree that it's a stupid -- very unhelpful -- error message.  Even those of us with decades in the biz were scratching our heads for a couple of minutes the first time we saw it.)

Comment: Updated the question... still not working with [NSNumber numberWithInt: clientNumber]... clientNumber is defined as NSInteger.  The problem appears to be the conversion of NSInteger to id, which I can't seem to figure out.

Comment: You should not still be getting  the "Implicit conversion" message if you're passing an NSNumber as the second parameter on that call.  (But note that you did not include the entire definition of that method -- you're missing the inContext parm.)

Comment: (Though you might get a different "Implicit conversion" message from numberWithInt, if passing an NSInteger.  Try numberWithInteger.)

Comment: You could also use the new literals syntax: `ClientInfo *clientSelected = [ClientInfo MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"aClientNumber" withValue: @(clientNumber) inContext:localContext];`

Comment: HotLicks:  please take your comment and make an Answer with it (the one about using [NSNumber numberWithInteger:clientNumber])... it got rid of the error, and I now understand what to do.  Thank you.

Comment: You can check the answer by @mipadi -- it's essentially the same and he posted about the same time.

Answer (score 36):

The parameter type for `withValue` is an `id` (a pointer). `NSInteger` is a scalar value (not an object) and cannot be converted to a pointer value implicitly.

This is purely a guess, but creating an `NSNumber` from the `NSInteger` might work:

```objectivec
NSNumber *val = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:clientNumber];
ClientInfo *clientSelected = [ClientInfo MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"aClientNumber" withValue:val inContext:localContext];
```

Comment: So how am I supposed to fix this?

Comment: XCode 4.5 now supports literal, with backward compatibility to iOS 4.3 so using `@(clientNumber)` looks more cleaner.

Answer (score -1):

As per your definition of method it's expecting and `id` and your are passing it a `NSInteger` aka `int`