# Implicit conversion of 'NSInteger' (aka 'unsigned int') to 'NSNumber *' is disallowed with arc

Tags: objective-c

I've written this piece of code:

```
    for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < 1000; j++) {
            int k = i * j;

            //This is the line were the error messages appears
            NSString *number = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", k];

            NSNumber *length = number.length;
            NSNumber *half = (length / 2);
```

What I want it to do, is to take the int `k`, convert it into a NSString named `number`, store the length of the string `number` in the NSNumber `length`, and half of that value in the NSNumber `half`.

However, when trying to convert the int `k` to the NSString `number` I get the error message:

"Implicit conversion of 'NSInteger' (aka 'unsigned int') to 'NSNumber *' is disallowed with arc"

Could someone help me figure out why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implicit conversion of NSInteger error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13957558/implicit-conversion-of-nsinteger-error)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`number.length` returns integer not `NSNumber`.

Correct it to :

```
NSInteger length = number.length;
NSInteger half = (length / 2);
```

If you really want to use NSNumber do like this: (Here I am boxing the integer to NSNumber object)

```
NSNumber *length = @(number.length); //same as [NSNumber numberWithInt:number.length]
NSNumber *half = @(number.length / 2);
```